# After npm install -g, command still not found?

Tags: macos, command-line, ffmpeg, homebrew, node.js

I don't know what's going on, but none of my installed node packages are actually registered.

`npm` and `node` work fine, but if I `sudo npm install -g` `ffmpeg` or `brew`, they're listed at `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` but `brew -v` and `ffmpeg -v` don't do anything "command not found"

> Any help is much appreciated, I'm pretty new with command line stuff. I think I'm confused on the difference between `npm` and `brew`... Does npm symlink to the command line, or only allow `require("brew")` within node instances?

One time, I did follow some instructions for registering "sublime" as a command line alias. Don't really think that should affect anything, but I don't even know where to look

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Is there anything displayed if you run `npm get prefix` ? (For example's sake, I'll say "/usr/local" is returned after running the command)

If anything is returned after running the above command, check what your PATH environment variable is set as by running `echo $PATH` (Again for example's sake, I'll say "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin" is returned after running this command)

If the prefix returned from `npm get prefix` is **not** shown in your PATH – which is true for the example above since "/usr/local/" is not in PATH – you will then have to set your PATH variable. To set your PATH:

If your shell is Bash, run: `export PATH="[prefix]/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile` where `[prefix]` is the returned value of `npm get prefix`

So, using "/usr/local" again as the example, replace "[prefix]" with "/usr/local" as shown below
`export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile`
then do
`source ~/.bash_profile`

(You said you are pretty new to command-line stuff, so if this does not make much sense, leave a comment and I will try to provide further clarification)

Comment: I can confirm this is working on macos High Sierra, thank you!

Comment: Still facing same problem.

Comment: `npm install -g` is not adding links to `$prefix/bin`, each executable is separated into their own package's install directory like `$prefix/lib/node_modules/$package/bin/`. When `-g` is not used, npm does add a convenient link directory of executables `./node_modules/bin`.